# Java:how come 2 literals(the same contents) in 2 classes use the same interned string?

Tags: java, string

```
class A {
    String s = "abc";
}

class B {
    String s = "abc";

     static public void main(String[]args ) {
            A a = new A();
            B b = new B();
            System.out.println("a.s==b.s : " + (a.s==b.s));
     }
}
```

The output:

```
a.s==b.s : true
```

If the literal is written to the "constant pool" part of the classfile,how come 2 literals(the same contents) in 2 classes use the same interned string? How does the compiler link them together?

Comment: They get interned at class loading time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a *string pool* into which all interned `String` objects go. It's effectively a `HashMap<String>`. Note that the `String.intern()` method returns a `String`; the implementation is essentially

```
if (stringPool.contains(this))
    return stringPool.get(this);
else {
    stringPool.put(this, this);
    return this;
}
```

When a String object is creating while loading a class, it's replaced by the result of calling `intern()`, which has the result of sharing like instances among all classes.

Comment: Thanks.So do you mean when loading 'class B', a new String object is created but then it is available for GC immediately since it's replaced by the interned string which is created when loading 'class A'?

Comment: Well, I was careful to say "effectively" and "essentially". There's certainly no requirement that it happen that way, and a clever implementation could avoid it.

Answer (score 4):

This is exactly as stated in the [Java Language Specification section 3.10.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.5):

> Moreover, a string literal always refers to the same instance of class String. This is because string literals - or, more generally, strings that are the values of constant expressions (§15.28) - are "interned" so as to share unique instances, using the method String.intern.

There's then an example, for which the explanation includes:

> Literal strings within different classes in different packages likewise represent references to the same String object.

[`String.intern()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#intern%28%29) is documented like this:

> Returns a canonical representation for the string object.
>
> A pool of strings, initially empty, is maintained privately by the class String.
>
> When the intern method is invoked, if the pool already contains a string equal to this String object as determined by the equals(Object) method, then the string from the pool is returned. Otherwise, this String object is added to the pool and a reference to this String object is returned.
>
> It follows that for any two strings s and t, s.intern() == t.intern() is true if and only if s.equals(t) is true.
>
> All literal strings and string-valued constant expressions are interned. String literals are defined in section 3.10.5 of the The Java™ Language Specification.

All of that points to the behaviour you've seen in your example.

Answer (score 1):

Imagine a `static final Set<String>` in the `String.class` that contains all interned strings. All classes that share the same loaded `String` class will see the same interned string. Since `String` is loaded by one of the root classloaders, it's shared by everything in a single JVM instance.